# What are the cryptic Steam Super Meat Boy achievements and what do the names mean?

Tags: pc, steam, super-meat-boy

It seems like the following [cryptic achievements](http://steamcommunity.com/stats/SuperMeatBoy/achievements) are only available on the Steam version, not XBLA.

- N#7*<1!23
- &*>?1$
- (=+66&1$
- ^**5%_=+12
- *|-0&&
- N&8^2^%$1``

The "description" on all of them is: 8*(@31^

#### Bonus (bounty) points:

Are the names/characters truly random or is there some pattern?  Can they be translated into something sane?

Comment: This is just a guess but I think they're related to the secret glitch levels that you can find by completing a level in each dark world under circumstances I don't quite understand yet.

Comment: Oh .. I thought they were named that way because the levels are notoriously hard, and that's what you end up with if you smash your keyboard. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mana's guess is correct. I can confirm that after beating Level -1 (in The Forest) I got the N#7*<1!23 achievement. Six worlds, six negative levels, six achievements.

See [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13200/under-what-circumstances-can-i-unlock-the-negative-levels-in-super-meat-boy) on how to reach the levels in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

The glitch Bandage girl occurs in the dark OR light world of the first 6 worlds when you die a lot. I think the number of deaths is somewhat randomized, but she makes funny bleeping sounds and is constantly morphing when she's "ready". Be sure you can get her in one shot though, because if you die again she goes back to normal and you have to die a bunch more times to maker her glitch again. As for the achievements, I'm not sure what the criteria are but it doesn't seem like you get the achievement when you beat it only, because I've beaten all of them and only have two glitch achievements.

Comment: The appearance of the glitched Bandage Girl is totally random; she could appear on the first or five hundredth attempt at a level with equal chance. I don't think the probability of her appearance is known, however.

Comment: Discussion relative to unlocking the glitch levels can be found [here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/13200/under-what-circumstances-can-i-unlock-the-negative-levels-in-super-meat-boy). A cute picture of a kitten can be found [here](http://www.innocentenglish.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2008/01/cats-kitten-sink.jpg).

Comment: @Mana +1 for kitten :p

Comment: Its Almost like a 1 in 100 chance of getting the "glitchy" Bandage girl.

Answer (score 1):

They're very well hidden warp zones in certain levels. I found and completed the first one, (found by completely random chance, completed in approx 1.5 hours) which unlocks the achievement. It appeared in the forest as a level coming before level 1. It is gold in colour and is known as world -1, an obvious nod to Mario. The only time I ever finished the level I luckily got an a+ on it.

Comment: They are not hidden -- they are unlocked by collecting the negative bandage girl from a dark world level.

Comment: They are not hidden. You must save the "glitchy" bandage girl in order to unlock the -1 glitchy level. Unfortunately, I don't know exactly how to get the bandage girl to become glitchy.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you die, there's a certain chance that Bandage Girl becomes glitchy (in that certain chapter - light or dark world doesn't matter). Save her in this glitchy state to unlock the glitch level of that chapter. Each one brings you an achievement when you beat it. As far as I know there is only A+ or death (or I somehow managed to get an A+ on everyone of the glitch levels at first try O_o). Not getting the achievement after beating the level is just a bug I think...but I'm not sure with that...