# Under what circumstances can I unlock the negative levels in Super Meat Boy?

Tags: super-meat-boy

While playing one of the dark world stages in Level 1 of Super Meat Boy, I reached the end of the stage after dying several times. However, Band-Aid Girl, instead of doing her normal crying animation, was messed up in appearance: glitchy and spinning around. Though I initially hesitated, I brought myself to touch her and complete the level, only to find myself in World -1. This stage was quite difficult and featured arcade-style play with only three lives as with the world zones. When I got game over and went back to the map screen, this stage was now accessible as a stage before the first stage of the Forest light world stages.

I managed to unlock the same sort of stage in the Salt Factory world.

I'm guessing that there are six of these, one for each of the normal worlds as well as the secret world. But I'm still not sure as to how I go about unlocking them.

Under what circumstances does Band-Aid Girl become glitched up, allowing me to unlock the negative levels? Is it determined by chance or do I have to die/not die a certain number of times to get her to become glitchy? Does this only occur on certain levels?

Comment: Wow. I was about to ask this question myself. Good timing!

Comment: Mana, can you confirm whether you are playing on PC or xbox?

Comment: @thethinman I'm playing on PC.

Comment: Considering there is a lot of useful information inside the answer comments, maybe the best action would be a community wiki answer that compiles the information gathered by everyone. Is it a good solution?

Comment: @Denilson There is a lot of useful information but most of it has been compiled into my answer. Do you feel that anything needs to be added? I will add it for you and if we keep adding things it will go community wiki within 5 edits anyways.

Comment: @thethinman you're right, most of it seems to be compiled in your answer. Anyway, you've missed the comment about being able to glitch the bandage girl on either Dark or Light levels, even though the glitch zone will show up in Light world map.

Comment: @Denilson Fixed, tell me if that's everything you think it needed.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Bandage girl has a random chance to glitch every time you spawn on a level. She can glitch in any level from 1 to 20 for each of the worlds 1 to 6, whether you're in the light or dark half of a world. There is exactly one negative level for every world.

To unlock level -1 for a world, pick a level in the world that is short and relatively easy. Below are good examples (in the light world) including a recommended character:

- 1-3 (The Gap) using anyone
- 2-10 (Johnny's Cage) using Jill (if you don't have Jill, see [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TpLVlyyFGmw&t=00m48s))
- 3-6 (The Shaft) using anyone
- 4-6 (Leviathan) using anyone
- 5-10 (Grinding Mill) using anyone
- 6-2 (Schism) using anyone

Then:

1. Look at or get to bandage girl and see if she is glitching. She will be spinning and making a distinctive pinging sound. I recommended levels where you can (mostly) see her from spawn.
2. If she is glitching then touch her to unlock level -1. Otherwise, kill yourself, respawn, and go back to step 1.
3. To play the level you just unlocked, go the light half of the world you unlocked it in. It will be available to play as a yellow-colored level beside level 1.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean Dark World? The negative bandage girl isn't obtainable in the Light world, only the dark world.

Comment: No, I've definitely unlocked her in the light world. I'm looking into the possibility that light and dark doesn't matter. On gamefaqs I've heard her being unlocked in both light and dark on world 6, and I've personally unlocked her using 1-3, 2-10, and 3-6 (light). ALso, here's a video of it being done in light (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYUc4I3lnaM)

Comment: Hm. That appears to be the xbox version of the game, though I don't know if that would necessarily change the answer of it.

Comment: Ah, good point. I am talking strictly PC, and I didn't check if those videos were referencing xbox. I will ask Mana to clarify.

Comment: I'm playing the PC version, and this week I unlocked a glitch zone while playing a dark world. However, the (golden) glitch level itself was available from the light world-map.

Comment: So you can unlock it from both worlds.

Answer (score 4):

If you continuously die, Band-Aid Girl should eventually become glitched. While she is glitched, standing next to her should teleport you to the negative level. And you are correct, there are negative levels for Worlds 1 - 6.

Here is [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYUc4I3lnaM) of somebody unlocking the first negative level.

Comment: Do you have a better cap on "continuously die"?

Comment: I believe it's completely random, so at some point after continuously dying, she'll become glitched. I'll search online some more to find a definitive answer though.

Comment: Hmm, I don't know if this is a coincidence or not, but in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYUc4I3lnaM) **and** [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFDCWnmvp2s), Band-Aid Girl becomes glitched after 6 deaths.

Comment: It's a coincidence. Interesting Fact: Bandage girl can become glitched *during the after level death recap*. If this happens, the replay freezes when the replayed meatboys reach her, stopping the loop (you can continue to the next level normally).

Comment: Actually, you don't really need to continuously die. When I first unlocked it, I was playing 1-3 (The Gap) while I was trying to get the "Wood Boy" achievement. I didn't die for the previous 2 levels, neither I had died in that level. So, the glitchy bandage girl might be completely random.

Comment: I suppose if it's random, there's always the chance of her being glitched on the first try.